# Installing sage in conda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, sage

So I have anaconda installed on windows which I assume is just as good as miniconda and after following the instructions here  https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html  I get the following output.

```
 The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - sage

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I found https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sage, but the install options tell me either I need to change my conda settings and further I don't understand or gives me this error again

Answer (score 4):

From the conda URLs in the error message, it looks like OP is using Windows. [Sage does not support installation via conda on windows](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html):

> SageMath can be installed from `conda-forge` on **Linux** and **macOS** running x86-64 that most current desktops and laptops use.

If you look at the sage files on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sage/files, only macOS and linux packages are listed.

See Sage's [instructions for installing on Windows](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#microsoft-windows-cygwin). That points you to https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/releases, which offer installer packages for sage on Windows.

Comment: Can I import sage into python?

Comment: One can use Conda to install Sage in WSL2 (or WSL) Linux subsystem.